# Extending core.logic to custom types

Tags: clojure, protocols, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic

I'm experimenting with [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic), and want to enable my own custom data type to participate in logic expressions:

```
(deftype Expression [node vars]
  ....)
```

Basically this represents a node in a mathematical expression tree, containing a node tree and a set of unbound variables used. `node` is either a constant, a symbol or an `(Operator Expression Expression....)` tree node. I'd like to be able to use core.logic to manipulate mathematical expressions, and match against subtrees of such expresssions.

How can I do this, if possible?

I see from the core.logic source code that there are a [number of protocols](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic/protocols.clj) that look like they would be good to extend (e.g. `IUnifyTerms`, `IReifyTerms` etc.) but it's not totally clear how these are all meant to be used, and which ones I really need to extend.

Comment: You might be interested in Term Rewrite Systems.  I've found that looking at existing implementations of what you're attempting have been fruitful (Maude, Stratego/XT are nice).  Also, be aware that you might run into the associative-commutative matching problem; a computationally challenging subproblem that existing core.logic machinery wouldn't support particularly well (last time I checked anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

core.logic is designed to extensible to custom types. However this is not well documented as the protocols are subject to change as we learn what exactly is needed. It's worth examining the `clojure.core.logic.nominal` namespace to get a sense of what's required to extend core.logic to custom types.